# netplan during boot

Tags: boot, networking, netplan

From all that I have been able to find so far, I am quite puzzled why anyone would ever want to use netplan on a serious machine such as a server when you want the network up during the boot process. So I am getting the feeling I am just missing something that isn't on the main wiki or any other place I can find.

How the heck can I make netplan do the simple thing that ifupdown does and bring the network online during boot before trying to mount network drives and perform other network related tasks?

I have 4 servers all running Ubuntu 18.04 but one is a fresh build where the others were upgraded so only the one is running netplan and the others appear to still be using ifupdown. The three with ifupdown work perfectly but the new one won't fireup the network until well after booting and I am left with no network drives (nfs) and things like apache that rely on those drives won't start because the drives are missing.

I have gotten around this by putting commands in my crontab that waits for several seconds, makes sure the network is running then mounts the drives and starts the services. But this is a joke of a solution when it should all be starting from the boot process.

Does anyone have a way to make netplan initialize the network during startup?

**>> Adding more detail <<**

My NFS is mounted in /etc/fstab on all machines and only this new machine has issue. The network interface does come online but it is well after the mount is attempted and to make it mount reliably, I had to add a 15 second delay in the crontab. Zero seconds never worked, 5 seconds workes many times 10 worked most of the time 15 seconds has worked every time.

```
crontab entry
@reboot sleep 15; mount -a

journalctl --no-pager -lu systemd-networkd
-- Logs begin at Mon 2018-05-21 06:11:07 PDT, end at Tue 2018-05-22 04:17:22 PDT. --
May 21 06:11:12 data1 systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
May 21 06:11:12 data1 systemd-networkd[1170]: Enumeration completed
May 21 06:11:12 data1 systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
May 21 06:11:12 data1 systemd-networkd[1170]: lo: Link is not managed by us
May 21 06:11:12 data1 systemd-networkd[1170]: enp31s0: IPv6 successfully enabled
May 21 06:11:15 data1 systemd-networkd[1170]: enp31s0: Gained carrier
May 21 06:11:16 data1 systemd-networkd[1170]: enp31s0: Gained IPv6LL
May 21 06:11:17 data1 systemd-networkd[1170]: enp31s0: DHCPv4 address 192.168.1.113/24 via 192.168.1.1
May 21 06:11:17 data1 systemd-networkd[1170]: Not connected to system bus, not setting hostname.
May 21 06:11:17 data1 systemd-networkd[1170]: enp31s0: Configured

networkctl
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP     
  1 lo               loopback           carrier     unmanaged 
  2 enp31s0          ether              routable    configured
```

Comment: How are you trying to do the NFS mount in `fstab`? Have you executed `systemctl daemon-reload` and checked for possible errors in `journalctl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

netplan does not in general have difficulty starting the network at startup.  Some places to look in order to debug this:

- the output of `journalctl --no-pager -lu systemd-networkd` - what network interfaces are taking a long time to configure, and why?
- the output of `networkctl` - are the expected interfaces up after boot, or not?

To see why a particular mount failed at boot, you can look at the journalctl output for the specific `.mount` unit.  For example, if you have `/mnt/nfs` as a remote mountpoint, you can run `journalctl --no-pager -lu mnt-nfs.mount`.

There is a bug reported against systemd that it tries to mount network filesystems too early, before the network is fully configured. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1577575  This bug is not yet confirmed by the developers, but it's possible that there are bugs here in systemd regarding the ordering.  I think that bug report will be the best place to track progress.

Comment: I updated my question to include answers to your questions. Netplan does activate the network card correctly just very late in the boot process. On the other machines, ifupdown waits for the network to initialize before letting the boot sequence to continue and they all boot correctly. Only this new box is having boot sequence issues.

Comment: ok, I've also updated the answer with more hints about debugging, and a pointer to open bug reports against systemd.

Comment: It does appear that I am a victom of the bug. I'll keep an eye on that bug report.